# What is the name of the problem where numerical ODE integration results in non-machine-representable value?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

When numerically solving an ODE, for example using a simple Euler method, if the step size is too large, the resulting next time step value of the target function could be so large that it is not machine representable (at least with double precision numbers). I would like to know if this problem has a formal name, and, if possible, some common strategies used by numerical integration software to avoid it.

Comment: Blowup?????????

Comment: As @RodrigodeAzevedo stated, we usually say the solution 'blew up' if the numerical solution gives results which aren't finitely representable on a computer. This usually stems from your numerical scheme being unstable for the problem at hand. There are loads of different strategies used to combat this, with the main ones being taking smaller step sizes, using _implicit_ instead of _explicit_ methods and using numerical schemes specifically constructed for a certain type of problem.

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like an informal, "everyone knows that one when they see it" type of problem?